# What is the difference between __stdcall and _stdcal?

Tags: visual-c++

What is the difference between `__stdcall` and `_stdcal`? And what is logic at all by putting variable counter of `_` mark?

Comment: Yes, green tick is how to improve it. If you question doesn't have any answers then don't worry. There will also be some times when the only answer, is not a right answer so you don't have to worry about getting 100%... just try and keep it up as best you can ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no identifier or keyword named `_stdcal`.  However, the MSVC compiler accepts both `_stdcall` and `__stdcall`, one or two underscores.

The single underscore is there because the language specification requires it.  Vendor specific identifiers in the global namespace or non-standard keywords must be prefixed by an underscore.

The double underscore is there because a vendor forever loses the battle with programmers that think they should use a leading underscore themselves in their own code.  Also present in other non-standard keywords, like `__interface` and `__m128`.  And in other compilers, like gcc's `__attribute__`.  Clearly you'll want to use the documented version, two underscores.